# How can I have Credence rsrc stop calling me?

Tags: scams

First of all I am child. I am 16 years old, I want the calling to stop. The calling started about 2 days ago I believe. They call me multiple times a day, I never answer because I have no idea what I am getting myself into.
During class today they called me once more, that's when I began to worry. So I did some research, and apparently they are a debt collecting agency. I don't owe anybody anything, not that I know of at least, I'm fed up. What do I do? I want this harassment to stop.

Comment: Welcome to the club... get a new phone number, or block the caller.

Comment: Related: [Received federal student loan collection letter, but never had one. What to do?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/49416/10997)

Answer (score 4):

The Privacy Right Clearinghouse has an excellent article titled [“How to Put an End to Unwanted or Harassing Phone Calls”](https://privacyrights.org/consumer-guides/how-put-end-unwanted-or-harassing-phone-calls). It discusses contacting your phone company to block the calls (however, this can often be done directly from your smartphone), when to call the police, and lots of other related information.

If blocking the call doesn’t work, take a look at the [FTC’s Debt Collection FAQ](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/debt-collection-faqs), which discusses what Debt Collectors are allowed and not allowed to do, and how to make them stop contacting you.